# Cannot get hyperlink to respond to click()

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jQuery and can't figure this out:

Here's the HTML

```
<a id="myid" name="myid" href="stub">click here</a>
```

and the jquery snippet:

```
 $("#myid").click(function() {
    alert('Hello from click');
 });
```

Yet when I click on the link no alert displays. Something basic no doubt,  What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, file this under "learning jQuery".

The hyperlink html was being loaded into a div via load() by clicking on a button after the document had loaded.

Fine, but the problem was that I was binding the event handler to the hyperlink ***before***  the element was created. Having used inline onlcick() for so long, it took me a while to figure it out the jQuery/Ajax way.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

Your code needs to be in a `document.ready` handler so it binds the click after the anchor itself is available in the DOM, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#myid").click(function(e) {
    alert('Hello from click');
    //stop the link from going to it's destination here if you need to using
    //e.preventDefault();
    //or:
    //return false;
  });
});
```

If it's not like this or at the very least after the element in the page, the `$("#myid")` selector won't find any elements...so it won't bind an `onclick` handler to anything.

Comment: You'll probably also want to return false to avoid navigating away to `stub`

Comment: @Stefan - Yes very true, *if* that's your goal :) Keep in mind there are lots of cases you want to do something and still leave the page afterwards as well :)

Comment: Yes, I should have included that I had it in document.ready (of course).  I tried return false and preventDefault() with no luck either.

Comment: @nullone - Do you have a link to the page? It's possible you have an error including the jQuery library itself.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me exactly as is. It then redirects to "stub", but that could be resolved with a `return false` in the `click` function.

Answer (score 0):

you can also put a pound (#) in your href in your `a` tag like this

```
<a id="myid" name="myid" href="#stub">click here</a>
```

so even without `return false` in your jquery code, it will not redirect to anything.